# IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS

Tags: php, paypal

My PHP code currently uses the following to Postback to PayPal. How do I update this to meet the new payment security standards coming into effect?

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) 
{
  //an error occurred...
} 

else 
{
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

  while (!feof($fp)) 
  {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

    if(strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
    {
      //all is well...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [This should be a useful guide](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) from Paypal Github depository.

Comment: Thank you @Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS, change your code as follows,

```
$fp = fsockopen( 'tls://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

PayPal recommends to use ipnpb.paypal.com endpoint in production environment.

Also, you need to change  HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 to comply with PayPal upgrades.

The Header you need to submit,

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen( $req ) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

For the sandbox change,

```
 $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
```

to

```
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
```

Comment: There's a couple of issues I see with this approach: 1) it doesn't address the  fact that he's still on HTTP/1.0 (see https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US); and 2) PHP's documentation explicitly says "ssl:// will attempt to negotiate an SSL V2, or SSL V3 connection depending on the capabilities and preferences of the remote host." (http://php.net/manual/en/transports.inet.php)  It doesn't mention anything about TLS, so I don't trust `ssl://` to negotiate a TLS connection.  `tls://` is a safer choice.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Matt. Thanks. You can use it as
$fp = fsockopen( 'tls://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

Please refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Comment: I neglected to add the rest of my original code. I've edited the question now to include it. So, I'll still just need to change the $fp assignment to: $fp = fsockopen( 'tls://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);, correct? And this is the preferable solution to using cURL, as first suggested?

Comment: Correct. Also, you need to change 
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
to 
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
to comply with PayPal upgrades, as mentioned above.

Comment: Please see my new post above starting: "The new code suggested above has now had a chance to be tested."

What to do about using HTTP/1.0 and posting to www.paypal.com rather than using HTTP/1.1 and posting to tls://ipnpb.paypal.com?

Comment: Have you debug the response? I suggest you to properly debug and take a good look at the response received. If you do, you would see that the VERIFIED response code is now followed by a \r\n.  Thus,  the conditional check (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) cannot be used without trimming off the \r\n. So, add  $res = trim($res);  before if(strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0){ … } check.

Or you could use it as if ( stripos ( $res, 'VERIFIED' ) !== false ){ … }

Also,  it would be better to close the connection - 
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

The original answer is still valid.

Comment: The suggested changes have been made. I'm now getting: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Yes, it's because you have not added HTTP host header. I will add it in to the answer above.

Comment: The header is now: $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"; I'll update this thread with the result after the next transaction.

Comment: The status is now: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: I had troubles making it work, in the end I copied your code above exactly. and yep it worked. I think I had to add the Connection: close    to make it work for sure. and I removed the User-agent, referer, and removed the server headers. something made it work. all good now.  This is a correct answer for sure!

Comment: There is a mistake in this answer: the host header should match the address provided to fsockopen. Host: ipnpb.paypal.com OR IF SANDBOX Host: ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things that need to be done:

- You're still on HTTP/1.0; you need to switch to HTTP/1.1.
- You need to switch to using TLS.

Most PHP setups nowadays should have cURL installed, so the easiest thing to do would be to use cURL.  To do this, the last four lines of your code would change to the following:

```
$curl = curl_init( 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );

if( 'VERIFIED' == trim( $response ) ) {
  // IPN verified by PayPal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new code suggested above has now had a chance to be tested.

This did NOT work:

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));

  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen( 'tls://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

This is what works:

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));

  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

What to do about using HTTP/1.0 and posting to www.paypal.com rather than using HTTP/1.1 and posting to tls://ipnpb.paypal.com?

Comment: You need to add `$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com\r\n";` and `$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";` after your `$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";` line.

Comment: The suggested changes have been made. I'm now getting: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Do you have a pastebin link where I could see the full code that's triggering the "Bad Request" response?

Comment: Take out the extra `\r\n` on line 11.

Comment: The extra \r\n has been removed, so it is now: $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";

Comment: The status is now: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: Ok, good. Could you please vote for the answer as it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar issue with Paypal IPN verification and using this code

// post back to PayPal system to validate

```html
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

If I understand the solution correctly, the new code should look like

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen( 'tls://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```